# Creating a trigger that records modifications on table A by inserting values in table B

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I'm having problems with the following trigger that records when an insertion with attribute 'numero'= 4 is made on table A by inserting into table B who made the modification and the number of entries with attribute 'numero'= 4 in table A. The problem seems to be the select * count but I can't figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
DELIMITER $
CREATE TRIGGER t_BI          
AFTER INSERT ON A
FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
      IF NEW.numero=4 THEN
        INSERT INTO B(name,nbLoc)
        VALUE(CURRENT_USER(),SELECT COUNT(*) FROM A WHERE numero = 4);
      END IF;
    END
$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: A trigger definition starts with `create trigger`.  And if you care about numero `4`, why does the code refer to `5`?

Comment: thanks for the reply, sorry I didn't copy the whole part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to store your count value in a variable first, and use that variable in the INSERT

```
DELIMITER $
CREATE TRIGGER t_BI          
AFTER INSERT ON A
FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
    
      DECLARE cnt INT;

      IF NEW.numero=4 THEN
      
        SET cnt = ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM A WHERE numero = 4) ;        
      
        INSERT INTO B(name,nbLoc)
        VALUE(CURRENT_USER(), cnt);
        
      END IF;
      
    END
$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, that's what I guessed I have to do but do you know why the other way doesnt work ?

Comment: @VelCrow I cant say for sure because you havent posted the error message. I think it falls into the following [Restrictions for Stored Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-program-restrictions.html) : _Within a stored function or trigger, it is not permitted to modify a table that is already being used (for reading or writing) by the statement that invoked the function or trigger._ And although you are not trying to modify the table that is already being used, you reference it in the INSERT, which MySQL might not like.

Comment: Well thank you again my problem is solved